# Interworking of Spring Data JPA @Query annotation and Hibernate @Where annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having an interesting issue with `@Where` annotation and `@Query` annotaion on a spring boot project, spring data jpa also is in the project as well.

Basically I have soft delete mechanism and this is to set a valid date for Entity (say property `valide_date` column with `validDate` property in the Entity class). These entities annotated with `@Where` annotation something like `@Where("valid_date > now()")`. This way the soft-deleted entites which has `valid_date` set to now and before are eleminated automatically. (e.g Entity class `User`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@SQLDelete(sql = "...") // to update valid date for soft deleting entity
@Where(clause="valid_date > now()") //to apply non deleted entity automatically
public class User {

    @OneToOne(...)
    BaseEntity base;
}
```

I also have some Other entities which does not have `valid_date`.(e.g Entity class `UserRequest`)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_request") //
public class UserRequest {

    @OneToOne(...)
    BaseEntity base;
}
```

And some other tables available as well. In case of Jpa Query annotated method. I am facing with some issues.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.foo.RequestListDto(B, S, I, U) from UserRequest B " +
        " left join fetch AnotherTable I on I.base = B.base" +
        " left join fetch User U on U.base = B.base" +
        " left join fetch UserRequest S on S.base = B.base " +
        " where B.id IN :idList")
```

Basically I am creating a request list DTO which is a collection different properties from different tables based on joining common properties.

When the method with above `@Query` annotation called; Looking at the generated sql ; I can not see the `valid_date > now ()` clause applied to User entity. "IF" the User entity is on join side as shown above. If I change the from clause to "`from User U`", then the valid_date rule applied to the query.

In summary;
`@Where` annotation applied only if the containing entity is located on from clause. But not applied if the containing entity is not on from clause.

Is there a specific reason for not applying the `@Where` annotation that I don't know? What should I do to get that `@Where` annotation applied automatically ?

Note : I can extend those "join on ..." clauses to `join on ... and U.validDate > :now` for `@Where` annotated Entities. But is this the only way ?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Where` annotation works exactly as it should work. Only in requests where the `from` is the annotated entity.
If you want to use it for `join` then you need to annotate the "join-definition" too - which is the property annotated by the `@OneToOne` annotation. You can add the `@Where` annotation to properties too. So add `@Where` annotation to the User property in the entity which you want to use in the `from` part of the query

```
@OneToOne(...)
@Where(clause="valid_date > now()")
User user;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I would not try to join a table if it is already in relationally mapped state of my from clause entity (in this case UserRequest). And for me also; Where annotation has some issues as well. Since the note on the source of Where says this is mostly useful on soft delete case. But here since that Where not applied on join side; soft deleted entities returned also.